Why inner iterators of groupby are consumed?
I have two versions of a script :
from itertools import groupby
for key, group in groupby('122333'):
    print(key, list(group))
# output
1 ['1']
2 ['2', '2']
3 ['3', '3', '3']

from itertools import groupby
for key, group in list(groupby('122333')):
    print(key, list(group))
# output
1 []
2 []
3 []

Why inner iterators of groupby are consumed in the second case ?

"The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible. So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list"
